# Attribute error module object has no attribute -- Caused by circular imports?

Tags: python-2.7, import

Module OTS

```
from Tkinter import *
import openTableApiGet

#bunch of code blah blah blah

openTableApiGet.main() # call to the method in the OpenTableApiGet module
```

Module OpenTableApiGet

```
import OTS

 class Parser:

#Bunch of code in the class doing stuff


def main(): 
#bunch of code

#The main method the complier says this module 
#doesn't have. Outside of `the Parser class, 
#just hanging out on its  own
```

Why is this happening? is the circular import to blame I'd rather keep it but If I must change it I will. I need to write more to make stackoverflow happy so I hope you find tacos in your life soon!

Thanks everyone

Comment: I import OTS for another reason other than the code shown in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the circular import makes the code you've shown fail in some circumstances. Specifically, if outside code imports the `OpenTableApiGet` module first, the `OTS` module will fail when it tries to call `OpenTableApiGet.main()`.

Here's why. When Python loads a module, it starts at the top and runs each statement sequentially. When it comes to an import statement, it *may* have to pause the execution of that module in order to load another module.

Here's an example:

A.py:

```
print 1
import B
print 3
```

B.py

```
print 2
```

These two simple will print the numbers 1-3 in order when you import `A`.

An import statement doesn't always pause though. If the module to be imported is already loaded (or in the process of being loaded in a circular import situation) Python will not load it again. It will just take a reference to the existent module object and put it into the importing namespace.

C.py:

```
print 1
import B
print 3
import B
print 4
```

Nothing will be printed when the second `import` statement is run, since the `B` module was already loaded (by the first `import` statement).

Here's a simple version of your modules that shows the issue with circular imports:

D.py:

```
print 1
import E
print 5    # this doesn't get a chance to run, nor the code below
x = 7
print 6
```

E.py:

```
print 2
import D
print 3
print D.x    # this causes an exception, since D doesn't have an x attribute yet
print 4
```

If you import `D`, you'll get 1-3 printed and then an exception when the code in `E` tries to access a global variable in `D` that hasn't been initialized yet. Note that `5` does not get printed before the exception, as `D`'s execution is paused waiting for `E` to finish loading.

There are a few ways to fix the code.

First a bad fix. There won't be an exception if you import `E` first, rather than `D` (though you'll get some of the numbers printed out of order). I don't recommend relying on this as a solution though, as if you change some imports around in later code it may break again and be very confusing!

Often the "best" approach is to reorganize the code to eliminate the circular dependencies between your modules. Either move some code from one module to the other or factor it out into a third module that both of them can import. This approach may be very vigorously advocated by programmers who learned programming with other languages where circular dependencies are always broken, but it's not nearly as big of an issue in Python.

Another option is to allow the circular import to stay, but simply to avoid doing too much stuff at the top level of the module. Often you can put the troublesome code into a function (that's called by code outside the module) and it will work despite the circular imports. If don't have any top level code that tries to access the contents of the other module, circular imports are not a problem, since not much actually gets run until the imports are complete and all the modules have been fully loaded.

Here's an example of that:

F.py:

```
print 2
import D
print 3
def foo():
    print D.x   # not at top level any more
print 4
```

main.py

```
import D, F
F.foo()
```